# Error: BindingExpression path error:

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, prism

I am using Win 8 Store Prism framework and have built a page and associated viewmodel.  I am trying to get my first binding to work but have failed an uncovering the cause of this error.  (I wish I could find a way to format the following error message better so you don't have that nasty scroll.  sorry)

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: '_Portfolios' property not found on 'PMPMgr.WinStore.PrismApp.ViewModels.HomePageViewModel, PMPMgr.WinStore.PrismApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='_Portfolios' DataItem='PMPMgr.WinStore.PrismApp.ViewModels.HomePageViewModel, PMPMgr.WinStore.PrismApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'Object')
```

I am trying to bind the following property to a listview like so:

```
private IEnumerable<Portfolio> _portolios;
public IEnumerable<Portfolio> _Portiolios
{
    get { return _portolios; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _portolios, value); }
}
```

View Model Code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding _Portfolios}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Category}"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an ObservableCollection and to remove the underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my new friend Brian who spotted the typo:  "_Portiolios"